# Accidentally breaking fast without eating

Tags: sawm

If I break my fast accidentally (not by eating) what is the ruling? can I continue or is my fast invalid?

Comment: broke it how?⠀⠀

Answer (score -2):

As long as it's an accident you're fine. Think of it as a gift from Allah.

Comment: Breaking it by e.g. intercourse will require Qada or even Kaffarah according to some madhabs.